# IF-Else condition not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

In below code outer if-else condition not working correctly.Highlighted condition equals to true then also control goes to else part instead of executing code inside if part.

Our requirement is to check if budgethours field has 0 then some fields should remain hidden and if not 0 then those fields would be visible.The control we are using to display data from dataset is inner repeater control.Thanks for help.

```
  protected void innerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)

  {
     try

    {

        cn = new SqlConnection(str);

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("TotalProjectDisplay", cn);

        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        myCommand.CommandText = "TotalProjectDisplay";

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        //condition here***
        if (ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["BudgetHours"].ToString()=="0")
        {

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Label lbbudgethours = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbbudgethours");
                lbbudgethours.Visible = false;
                Label lbRemainingBudget = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbRemainingBudget");
                lbRemainingBudget.Visible = false;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Label lbbudgethours = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbbudgethours");
                lbbudgethours.Visible = true;
                Label lbRemainingBudget = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbRemainingBudget");
                lbRemainingBudget.Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();

    }

}
```

Comment: check if there is an exception because as i can see your controls are by default visible

Comment: Have you checked what value is actually stored in the place you're checking?

Comment: there are two datasets so first dataset at 0 index is for outer repeater and second dataset is for inner repeater which has BudgetHours field

Comment: Are you getting data in `DataSet` ?

Comment: So if you put `ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["BudgetHours"].ToString()` in a watch, what value are you getting back?

Comment: Yes we are getting correct data means 0 for BudgetHours field

Comment: Then use `.Trim()` like `ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["BudgetHours"].ToString().Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your if condition with

```
if (Convert.ToInt32("0" + ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["BudgetHours"])==0)
```